# printf と puts の違いはなんですか？

Tags: c

C言語において、`printf` と `puts` という2つの標準出力のための関数がありますが、この2つはどのように違うのでしょうか？

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
  printf("hello world");
  puts("hello world");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「文字列を出力する」という役割は同じですが、`printf` ではどのように出力するのかフォーマットを細かく指定できるのが特徴です。

printf では `%` 記号から始まる "変換指定子" と出力したい "変数" のペアを指定するのが一般的な使い方で、数値の桁数や文字列の出力幅、右寄せ or 左寄せなどを指定できます。

https://www.k-cube.co.jp/wakaba/server/func/fprintf.html

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int i;
    printf("%d\n", 200);   /* 200  */
    printf("%i\n", 200);   /* 200  */
    printf("% d\n", 200);  /*  200 */
    printf("% d\n", -200); /* -200 */
    printf("%+d\n", 200);  /* +200 */
    printf("%+d\n", -200); /* -200 */
    printf("%o\n", 200);   /* 310  */
    printf("%#o\n", 200);  /* 0310 */
    printf("%x", 200);     /* c8   */
    printf("%#x", 200);    /* 0xc8 */
    printf("%#X\n", 200);  /* 0XC8 */
    printf("%f\n", 123.456);               /* 123.456000        */
    printf("%10.2f\n", 123.456);           /*     123.46        */
    printf("%010.2f\n", 123.456);          /* 0000123.46        */
    printf("%e\n", 123.456);               /* 1.234500e+02      */
    printf("%E\n", 123.456);               /* 1.234500E+02      */
    printf("%10.3e\n", 123.456);           /* 1.235e+02         */
    printf("%g\n", 123.456);               /* 123.456           */
    printf("%g\n", 0.0000123456);          /* 1.23456e-05       */
    printf("[%c]\n", 'h');                 /* [h]               */
    printf("[%*c]\n", 5, 'h');             /* [    h]           */
    printf("This is a %s.\n", "string");   /* This is a string. */
    printf("[%s]\n", "overlength");        /* [overlength]      */
    printf("[%*s]\n", 5, "overlength");    /* [overlength]      */
    printf("[%.*s]\n", 5, "overlength");   /* [overl]           */
    printf("Address: %p\n", main);         /* Address: 00401330 */
    printf("this many of chars are written so far:%n", &i);
    printf("%d\n", i); /* this many of chars are written so far:38 */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

puts()は、引数を持つことができません。
また、出力末尾に改行を含みます。

printf()は、引数を持たせることができます。
ex.) printf("%d", a);
出力末尾に改行は含みません。